# Modeling Users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations, sti

I need advice/help in implementing the design of my models in a university HR web application that I'm currently developing.

First, I have these models for my tables with their fields:

```
Students
 * different fields
Faculty
 * different fields
Users
 * username
 * password_digest
```

I have Students and Faculty objects for CRUD that have their unique fields/attributes in their own tables. At the same time, I see these objects as the types of Users that uses the app.

I'm confused on how to model them properly, experimenting either with ActiveRecord's STI or Polymorphism techniques. All I want the app to do is to recognize the type of User that is signing in and then display or redirect to the appropriate page for that type of User. At the same time have reference to its associated record in the Faculty or Student table.

What is best way to approach this assuming I have these conditions:

- Users can either be a Student, Faculty, or Admin. Later on I can add/model non-faculty members to the applicaton as well.
- Student/Faculty can opt to have or not have an associated User account. (Some students and faculty members don't want to use the app)
- Admin users have access to the administrative (CRUD) side of the app. Student and Faculty can only handle their own records.

I might be wrong, but my bet is to go polymorphic and put the reference in the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :userable
end

class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :userable
end
```

P.S.: I don't know if the "userable" term sounds right, just correct me if there's a better way to name it.

Answer (score 0):

One Simple method is, So you can easily manage with common fields as well

```
# User should have a type field (string)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Student < User

end

class Faculty < User

end
```

Comment: How will I add new records to my Student object/table if I inherit from the User model? This doesn't add up.

Answer (score 0):

This spells out very clearly the way you need to go:

*"Student/Faculty can opt to have or not have an associated User account. (Some students and faculty members don't want to use the app)*"

This means that Student, Faculty and User need to be completely different things: you need to be able to have a Faculty account which doesn't have a user account.  So, your polymorphic approach is the right way to go i think.

BTW, i would rename Faculty, since Faculty has a different meaning:  a faculty is a department or division within the university, it's not a person.  Later on in your app's development you may need to associate classes, students or staff members with a Faculty and then it's going to get confusing.  I would use FacultyMember since that's how staff are usually described.

"userable" **is** an awkward word to use for the relationship.  What about "scholar"?  That can describe both staff and students, and it conveys the idea that it's referring to an actual person, as opposed to "user" which is really a **user account** rather than a person.

Comment: Thumbs up for the FacultyMember tip!